# Python "OverflowError: math range error"

Tags: python, math, overflow, range

I'm new to Python and i'm having trouble with this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
b = 1-exp(n)*erfc(n**0.5)
```

OverflowError: math range error

I need to calculate 'b' for ever increasing values of 'n' and i don't know what to do to solve this problem.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What number of `n` gives you the error?  What library did you `import` to get `exp` and `erfc`?

Comment: n = 709.782118661. I've imported from math

Comment: A computer cannot represent an arbitrarily large number.  If you try to go past that threshold, you get an `OverflowError`.  You might consider reducing your numbers in size in the computation itself, then performing a transformation on the result to get the value you seek.

Comment: I understand that this is the problem, but i don't know how to reduce the size of the number i'm working with. Can you explain or give me some reference please?

Comment: It depends on the equation.  @ZSG has a great suggestion in taking the log of `n` in the calculation.  You can then do the antilog afterwards.  Make sure you do this out on pencil and paper first to make sure you get your equation correct.

Answer (score 3):

While the final answer is small, the exp(n) becomes huge, quickly becoming larger than can fit in a float.  For example:

```
from math import exp, erfc
n=100
b = 1-exp(n)*erfc(n**0.5)
print b
print exp(n)
```

Produces:

0.943859007256

2.68811714182e+43

You can use numpy if you have to manipulate huge numbers.

You may also choose to take the log of both sides and compute in order to knock out the exp term.